# AndEngine Update

Tags: java, android, andengine, physics

I'm trying to learn AndEngine and have been messing around with the examples. The one I am modifying is [PhysicsJumpExample](https://raw.github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/PhysicsJumpExample.java)

What I would like to do is run something every X seconds. I have done some searching and have found people suggesting:

```
this.scene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {
@Override
public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Your code to run here!
}
```

But I find I cant do this probably because of:

```
this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsWorld);
```

How would I go about running code every X seconds?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register a timer handler like this:

```
protected Scene onCreateScene() {
    Scene myScene = new Scene();  // somewhere you create your scene
    float xSeconds = 5.5f; // meaning 5 and a half second
    boolean repeat = true; // true to reset the timer after the time passed and execute again
    TimerHandler myTimer = new TimerHandler(xSeconds, repeat, new ITimerCallback() {
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            methodWithStuffToDo();
        }
    });
    myScene.registerUpdateHandler(myTimer);   // here you register the timerhandler to your scene

    .... // some other stuff
    return myScene;
}
```

Then you write in your scene a method that implements the code you want to execute when the timer is finished:

```
public void methodWithStuffToDo(){ ... }
```

Explanation:

The TimerHandler will be checked in the `onUpdate`method of the update thread. When it is close to the indicated time (here 5.5 seconds) the onTimePassed method will be triggered. I say *close*, because the UpdateThread will not necessarily be exact up to the last millisecod. That is basically the same as the suggestion in your code, with the difference that the TimerHandler will actually handle the update method and decide when to do what (which is simpler than creating one's own UpdateHandler).

Comment: sorry for being a complete moron but where should I implement this code, so far I have tried on onCreateScene() and onResumeGame() but i keep on getting errors like "The constructor TimerHandler(float, boolean, new ITimerCallback(){}) is undefined"

Comment: sorry, there was a little mistake in the code. I tried it in my Activity, and this one works for me. Actually you should be able to create your TimerHandler where ever you want and register it to any sort of Scene, Entity or Sprite in you Project. Here I did include it in the onCreateScene() (so it is in the activity, the methodWithStuffToDo is also in the activity, and the handler gets registered to the scene).